# why head -5 /filepath and head -n 5 /filepath shows the same output?

Tags: command-line, syntax

I'm sorry for this silly question but i'm new to terminals and i don't quite understand how we can pass a number of lines without an option.

Even the man page says:

```
-n, --lines=[-]NUM
              print the first NUM lines instead of  the  first  10;  with  the
              leading '-', print all but the last NUM lines of each file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes the man page doesn't tell the whole story. In this case you need to look at `info head` to see

> For compatibility ‘head’ also supports an obsolete option syntax
> ‘-[NUM][bkm][cqv]’, which is recognized only if it is specified first.

GNU publishes their ***full*** manuals as info pages. Also as HTML online:

- [listed by package](https://www.gnu.org/software/)
- for coreutils, maybe [the index](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Concept-index.html#Concept-index) is the easiest way to look up a particular command.